# How to update contacts associated with Account using put method in salesforce?

Tags: apexrest

I didn't display the Accounts of contacts. how to solve the above scenario please give some ideas.can you give me example program of that scenario.

Comment: 'salesforce', your question may be easier to understand if you provide more details and context of what you're trying to do. Help us help you.

Comment: give one example for that one

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code snippet in anonymous

List l = new list();
for( Account a : [select id, name, (select id, lastname from contacts) from Account where id=: '// id of account']){
a.contact.name = a.contact.name+' test';
// update the fields which you want, and dont forget to query those fields in the loop above
l.add(a);
}

update l;